# Solving for $x$ in a system of equations with 2 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$a^2-b^2-c^2=x^2-y^2\quad \&\quad
ab=xy$$

Hi. So I have been trying to solve this equation (I'm looking for $x$, and $x$ and $y$ are the only variables) but I just can't find a solution. Please help. How do I find an expression for $x$?

Comment: You can use the 2nd one to eliminate $y$ from the first to give a quadratic in $x^2$. there may be a neater way.

Comment: But still, both sides will still have x. :(

Comment: You should end up with $x^4-(a^2-b^2-c^2)x^2-a^2b^2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply all terms by $x^2$ 
$x^2(a^2-b^2-c^2)= x^4-(xy)^2$ then it turns out to be 
$(x^2)^2-x^2(a^2-b^2-c^2) -(ab)^2=0$ 
Use quadratic formula